# Get HTML source of a https page by forcing a user agent in Ruby

Tags: ruby, facebook, https, screen-scraping, http-status-code-302

```
>>require 'net/https'
>>uri = URI('https://www.facebook.com/careers/department?dept=product-management&req=a2KA0000000E147MAC')
>>conn = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
>>req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, {'User Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1'})
>>resp = conn.request req
=> #<Net::HTTPFound 302 Found readbody=true>
```

The 302 redirection thrown by the website redirects to a 'unsupported browser' page. What am I doing wrong in setting the user agent for this request? I'm using the same user agent string returned by browser. 
Additional info: I cannot use libraries such as watir in this use case. Any solution by using either 'net/http[s]' or 'open-uri' would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change 'User Agent' to 'User-Agent' with a hyphen.